# How to setup artifact filters to differentiate for deployment

Tags: azure-devops

We would like to deploy only the artefacts that are built from our dev branch to the dev environment.

and master branch to be deployed to staging(stage) and production(PRD) environments

As a tool, we are using VSTS

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtT3B.jpg

How should we coordinate this process if we can not implement artefact filters in VSTS?

I am considering to create a separate container registry for master builds

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzcve.jpg

Wanted to learn the best practice before i implement this

Comment: great question....Azure DevOps does not support the artifact filters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure DevOps supports artifact filters for each environment. Below is screenshot of how to enable the feature.

[image: Azure DevOps supports Artifact Filters in Environments]

Comment: Is that with the new update ?

Comment: I remember using this for quite sometime (3 months)

Comment: This has been available for almost a year.

Comment: thanks for comments